# jupyter notebook %matplotlib error

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

My system is Ubuntu 15.04 64bit.
My python version:

```
**:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
```

My ipython version:

```
**:~$ ipython
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:08:32) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 4.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

I have use `conda install matplotlib`, `conda install numpy`, and `conda install scipy`. 
Version and location

```
# packages in environment at /home/hust/anaconda2:
numpy                     1.10.4                   py27_1  
matplotlib                1.5.1               np110py27_0  
scipy                     0.17.0              np110py27_3
```

In ipython,

```
In[1] %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: Qt4Agg
In[2] from pylab import*
```

It's all right.

In order to new a `python2` in jupyter notebook, I use these command found in [Kernels for Python 2](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html)

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2    
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Now by entering `jupyter notebook` in the terminal, and new a `python2`. I try to use `%matplotlib`

```
In[1]: %matplotlib
ImportError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f64cd8484500> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'matplotlib')

/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython       /core/interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s)
2161         magic_name, _, magic_arg_s = arg_s.partition(' ')
2162         magic_name = magic_name.lstrip(prefilter.ESC_MAGIC)
-> 2163      return self.run_line_magic(magic_name, magic_arg_s)
2164 
2165      #-------------------------------------------------------------------------

/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in run_line_magic(self, magic_name, line)
2082        kwargs['local_ns'] =     sys._getframe(stack_depth).f_locals
2083        with self.builtin_trap:
-> 2084     result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
2085        return result
2086 

<decorator-gen-106> in matplotlib(self, line)

/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.pyc in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
191       # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
192       def magic_deco(arg):
--> 193   call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
194 
195       if callable(arg):

/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magics/pylab.pyc in matplotlib(self, line)
98          print("Available matplotlib backends: %s" % backends_list)
99        else:
--> 100     gui, backend = self.shell.enable_matplotlib(args.gui)
101         self._show_matplotlib_backend(args.gui, backend)
102 

/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.pyc in enable_matplotlib(self, gui)
2937      """
2938      from IPython.core import pylabtools as pt
-> 2939   gui, backend = pt.find_gui_and_backend(gui, self.pylab_gui_select)
2940 
2941      if gui != 'inline':

/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.pyc in find_gui_and_backend(gui, gui_select)
258     """
259 
--> 260 import matplotlib
261 
262     if gui and gui != 'auto':

ImportError: No module named matplotlib
```

It turns out wrong.

I do install `matplotlib`, `scipy` and `numpy` in the conda environment. And it seems work well in the ipython but not in the jupyter notebook. What is the reason? I will appreciate it very much if you could help me with this.

Comment: The notebook is running code in the `ipykernel_py2` environment you set up. You need to install matplotlib in that environment.

Comment: Oh, thank you again. Now by using the pyenv, it goes all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem.

In terminal:

```
ipython
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.path
Out[2]: 
['',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/bin',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.3.5-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/hust/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/hust/.ipython']
```

But in jupyter notebook, the sys.path is:

```
 ['',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python27.zip',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
  '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-20.7.0-py2.7.egg',
  '/home/hust/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
  '/home/hust/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
  '/home/hust/.ipython']
```

Then I remember I have used the following codes to create a python2 kernel.

```
conda create -n ipykernel_py2 python=2 ipykernel
source activate ipykernel_py2    
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

In the [website](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/kernel_install.html)'s description, if you’re running Jupyter on Python 3, you can set up a Python 2 kernel like this. But actually I am running Jupyter on Python 2, the reason why I could not new a python2 script in jupyter notebook should be something else.

Finally, I realize that it is better to master all the pythons' environment via [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/). I should firstly install pyenv and then I only need use these commands, `pyenv install anaconda-2.4.0` , `pyenv global anaconda-2.4.0` and `jupyter notebook`.